# Reflection throws Exception. Why?

Tags: java

OK for example I have this code:

```
class Document {

// blablabla

}
```

and my main:

```
Object cl =Class.forName("Document"); // throws ClassNotFoundException: Document
```

Why it cannot find my class definition?

Comment: Please show us the WHOLE class, and at least your complete definition of `main`!

Comment: Is Document class is under any package?

Comment: Sorry, i tried to make a post quick, so possibly there is not a lot of info. And it is only a concept to understand syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the class is actually in a package. [`Class.forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) takes the fully-qualified name, as document:

> Parameters:
>   *className* - the fully qualified name of the desired class.

For example:

```
package foo.bar;

class Document {}

...

Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("foo.bar.Document");
```

If it's a *nested* class, you need to take that into account too:

```
package foo.bar;

class Outer {
    static class Document {
    }
}

...

Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("foo.bar.Outer$Document");
```

Answer (score 5):

you should refer to your class with it's fully qualified name:

```
Object cl =Class.forName("org.yourpackage.Document");
```

Comment: I'd bet he didn't use any packages and it `Document` IS the fully qualified name ;)

Comment: It is in the same package ,nevertheless should I refer full name?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is the SAME package. if it is in ANY package, you have to prefix it in Reflection.